# Using os.path.splitext to seperate filename and extension

Tags: python, path, split

I am creating a program in which I need to separate the file name and the file extension of a fle. The way i am doing this is by using

```
os.path.splitext('')
```

I was simply wondering if anybody knows how I could save the two parts of the file as two variables.

Comment: `name, extension = os.path.splitext(...)`?

Answer (score 6):

`os.path.splitext()` returns a tuple:

```
>>> import os
>>> name_parts = os.path.splitext('data.txt')
>>> name_parts 
('data', '.txt')
```

You can take it apart:

```
>>> body, ext = name_parts
```

Now:

```
>>> body
'data'
```

and:

```
>>> ext
'.txt'
```

You can do this in one step:

```
>>> body, ext = os.path.splitext('data.txt')
```

This is called tuple unpacking.

​For example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
```

You can swap their values with:

```
>>> a, b = b, a
```

You can also place parenthesis around. It is not necessary but may
help to understand what is going on:

```
>>> (a, b) = (b, a)
```